# Asdf wont switch local version based on tool-versions or using the local command

Tags: ruby, asdf-vm

I downloaded asdf the other day and am trying to use it with a ruby on rails project I downloaded from Github.
When I run `asdf install`, I get this response:

```
firebase 9.10.0 is already installed
ruby 2.7.2 is already installed
```

Then I run `rails s` :

```
No preset version installed for command rails
Please install a version by running one of the following:

asdf install ruby 2.7.2

or add one of the following versions in your config file at 
/Users/******/Desktop/****/.tool-versions
ruby 3.0.1
```

The project runs on ruby 2.7.2.

.tool-versions:

```
ruby 2.7.2
node 12.18.3
```

I installed asdf with homebrew and use oh-my-zhs with the asdf plugin.

EDIT:
running

```
asdf install ruby 2.7.2
```

just says

```
ruby 2.7.2 is already installed
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to reshim ruby. Run `asdf reshim ruby` and then try running `rails s` again.

Comment: So weird, the command line was saying the right version when I checked `asdf current` or did `ruby -v` but this seems to have fixed it  thanks! Saved me a big headache. I wonder why they do not do this automatically when installing/changing versions? There must be a reason because it seems too trivial to not just do it. Seems there's some info here: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby/issues/63

Comment: Thanks; the reshim command worked for the same issue I was having with kubectl not switching versions with asdf.   `adsf reshim kubectl`

Comment: If this doesn't work, check if you have added `. /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh` to ~/.zhrc file.

Answer (score 17):

### For RubyMine users

If you run the terminal commands inside of your integrated RubyMine terminal, nothing will change until you change the project SDK to the newly installed version. After restarting your terminal, everything should work as expected.

Here's where you can find the setting, check the box next to the sdk you want to use for the project:
[image]

Comment: How do i add asdf SDK to rubyMine. I am not able to figureout the location of this. I Have installed asdf using rosetta on my Apple silicon.

Comment: Hey @Divnoorsinghkang, if you don't have the asdf SDKs in the Settings like in the screenshot, then you might need to ask a new question. I think I had this issue once and resolved with reshims and properly installing asdf.

Answer (score 14):

For people experiencing this issue, who've installed asdf via Homebrew and who are using the standard ZSH shell (no oh-my-zsh plugins), don't forget to source the asdf bash script:

```
echo -e "\n. $(brew --prefix asdf)/libexec/asdf.sh" >> ${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.zshrc
```

Comment: And for those who are using BASH: echo -e "\n. $(brew --prefix asdf)/libexec/asdf.sh" >> ${ZDOTDIR:-~}/.bash_profile

Comment: dont forget to resource `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: After dealing with asdf for countless hours, this is what helped me. Such a simple line that solved all my problems.

Answer (score 6):

The following steps given by [purplespline](https://www.reddit.com/user/purplespline/) that I found in this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/nch9un/trouble_with_asdf_and_rubyrails/) worked for me:

```
asdf exec gem install rails
```

then you should be able to run other rails commands.

Answer (score 5):

If Ruby 2.7.2 is already in your `.tool-versions` file, you can fix this by simply running

```
$ bundle
```

This will install the correct version of the Rails gem and everything should work again.

Try looking at the output of `shim-versions` first and you will most likely see that Ruby 2.7.2 is there, but Rails 2.7.2 is not:

```
$ asdf shim-versions rails
ruby 2.7.0

$ asdf shim-versions ruby
ruby 2.7.2
ruby 2.7.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You should install bundle gem first

```rb
gem install bundle
```

then you can run `bundle` or `bundle install`

Comment: This was it for me. Forgot to run bundle and the error wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3):

On my end I did not export or add this on my `zshrc`

```
. /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh
```

And resource

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. I had forgotten to `bundle` after updating.

```
asdf plugin-update ruby
asdf install ruby 3.1.4
bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I just reinstalled rails.

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 0):

for diagnostics, please check out outputs of

which ruby

and

ruby --version

in the working directory of your project. If it indeed shows you ruby version 2.7.2, then run "gem install rails" or ("bundle install" if gemfile.lock is present) from this working directory again.

One common mistake is not to open new shell after modification of shell config files. Also zsh requires to run "rehash" command if some program is installed at different path, but reopening shell will solve that.

Answer (score 0):

One more tip: check if you have updated `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` as in the installation guide.

Answer (score -1):

Once Homebrew is installed, you can use it to install Ruby.

brew install ruby
This will install the latest Ruby version on Homebrew (which is 2.5.0 at the time of this writing) on /usr/local/bin/ruby. Add /usr/local/bin to the start of your PATH so it becomes the default Ruby.

Add this to ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile.

> export PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH'

If you’re using Ruby to run a few scripts then using the Homebrew version is enough

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: unclear what version you are talking about when you say 2.5.0. ruby 2.5.0 is deprecated for about 3 years. 2.7.x is going EOL in April, and 3.3.0 is scheduled to be release on Dec 25th. Homebrew I have is version 4.1.17. The question is about asdf. not about installing ruby in some other ways. and why hacking the PATH manually?